# Ignore data value for execute ... detect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to avoid specifying the data value when using the detect syntax of execute (`execute ... detect ~ ~ ~ ...`)?

I want to execute on an item and detect if there is stone under it and an anvil at ~+1 ~ ~, but the problem is that an anvil facing towards +x has a different data value than one facing towards -x etc. Do you know any way in Minecraft Vanilla to ignore this data value or put there universal one? (I can't just stop command because i need `<command>` that is after `<data value>`)

At the moment command looks like that:

```
execute @e[type=Item] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone 0 execute @e[type=Item] ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~ ~ minecraft:anvil <data value> say hi
```

Comment: As of 1.13, there is no such thing as a "data value", making this question obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### -1 fits all possible data values

From the wiki entry on [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) (emphasis mine):

> *block* and *data* (`detect` mode only)
>
> Specifies the block id and data which the block at (x2,y2,z2) must match for the command to run. *block* must be a valid block id (for example, `minecraft:stone`), **and *data* must be a valid block data for that type of block or `-1` to match any block data**.

This use of -1 is not limited to execute. Other commands, such as [`testforblock`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblock) also work like this.

Comment: I'm so stupid. All commands, data tags and things like these are frome gamepedia, but oh my god i didn't notice that. Thank you so much!

Comment: However sory i can't give you +1 cause of my low reputation :(

Comment: @HardnerPL Don't worry about it. Also, you do now.